# Spline Lineage failing while creating spark context

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I activate lineage for my pipelines - I'm submitting all the required artifacts (JARs) through spark.jar argument. Still, I get

```
sc._jvm.za.co.absa.spline.core.SparkLineageInitializer.enableLineageTracking(spark._jsparkSession)

spark._jsparkSession
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

anything specific I should add for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's the same issue that is explained in [this post](https://discuss.hail.is/t/typeerror-javapackage-object-is-not-callable/250)

> This usually means that the jar file isn’t set correctly. The way to pass it in is with the SPARK_CLASSPATH environment variable.